# Can we have a multi-page JPEG image?

Tags: c#, image, tiff

Can we have a multi-page JPEG image?

I have a TIFF image file with multiple pages, but it's too big and first thing comes to mind is to change it to JPEG format, however in JPEG I can see only first page. Therefore I realized only TIFF format allows multiple images in one file. Is that true?

Now I tried to apply different `EncoderParameters` to reduce the size of TIFF file but no luck. Has someone worked on this issue before? How did you manage to reduce the size of TIFF image?

`Encoder.Quality` does not seem to work with TIFF at all.
`EncoderValue.CompressionLZW` is the best option to reduce the size, but I still want to reduce the size more.

Changing dpi to 50 reduced the size, but that made image too blurry.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, JPEG does not support multi-page images. TIFF is the appropriate format for doing so. Change the DPI to something higher than 50 that still gives you acceptable qualities for your needs.

Comment: TIFF is pretty heavy image format. If you want to reduce the size of your image, you definitely need to convert it to another format. You can convert your TIFF to multiple JPEG or PNG images, and then ZIP them together in a single file if there is a need to store in a single file.

Comment: Can you use a TIFF file with JPEG compression for each image/page in the TIFF?

Answer (score 6):

JPEG is technically a image compression, the JPEG file type is actually JFIF which does not support multi-frames. TIFF is an image container that does support the JPEG compression algorithm though, so you should be able to save the TIFF file as small as saving each page as a seperate JPEG added up.

Here is a stackoverflow post that goes into more detail on how to achieve this:

[Create multipage Tiff with JPEG compression .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814254/create-multipage-tiff-with-jpeg-compression-net)

Comment: The B.6 section of T.81 spec seems to support multi-frame in jpeg, though not in the sense of frame as page

Answer (score 0):

It is possible througt the use of XMP. Android is using this for their new UltraHDR format which is backwards compatible with standard jpeg.

There is a library for it. https://github.com/google/libultrahdr